# Googles Maps "Tilt"/perspective view not avalaible from API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to display a perspective view of a satellite map. 
I used [sample code](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/aerial-simple?hl=FR)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>45° imagery</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.964645, -122.01523),
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(45);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I change the coordinates of the map for [this one](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Port+Albert/@47.5659812,-0.6052572,504m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x48087cf8b092e923:0x2cfaf35a9de4a685): 47.566188, -0.610760, I get several 404 not found which may mean that the perspective view is not avalaible, while it's avalaible in the maps application.

Could you have a explanation of my problem, and eventually a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why 45° imagery would be available on Google Maps and not in the API. I have tried with the v3 of the API (not v3.exp) and the same happens for these coords.

But if you want to avoid trying to load unavailable tiles and the 404 errors, you can do a very simple check:

```
if (map.getTilt()) {

    map.setTilt(45);
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ak8uF/)</kbd>